# Generating the sigma algebras on the set of probability measures

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, measure-theory

I was wondering if somebody could help me see/provide a reference to the following fact: Let $X$ be a metrizable set, $\mathcal{F}$ the corresponding Borel sigma-algebra on $X$, and $\triangle\left(X,\,\mathcal{F}\right)$ be the corresponding set of probability measures.

Suppose we endow $\triangle\left(X,\,\mathcal{F}\right)$ itself with the sigma-algebra generated by sets of the form

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ A\left(E,\, p\right)=\left\{ {\mu\in\triangle\left(X,\,\mathcal{F}\right)\,|\,\mu\left(E\right)\geq p}\right\} 
 ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,E\in F,\,\,\ p\in[0,\,1]$

Then the above sigma-algebra coincides with the Borel sigma-algebra generated by the weak * topology.

Comment: Basic open sets are defined by conditions such as $\int f\, d\mu > a$ for fixed continuous $f$. It should be routine to check (at least if it's true) that these sets can be manufactured from your $A(E,p)$'s and vice versa.

Comment: Also posted on MSE (which might be the better place for the question): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122089/equivalence-of-sigma-algebras-on-the-set-of-probability-measures

Comment: @ChristianRemling Would that not be equivalent to showing that the $A\left(E,\, p\right)$'s generate the weak * topology? The statement that I've seen is that the sigma-algebra generated directly from the $A\left(E,\, p\right)$'s, and not from the topology they generate, is what coincides with the weak * Borel algebra.

Comment: @Mark: The $A$'s don't look open to me, but one half of what I need to show is that $\sigma(A(E,p))$ contains all (weak $*$ relatively) open sets.

Comment: @ChristianRemling So, it can be shown that for each $E\in F$, the function $\mu\mapsto\mu\left(E\right)$ is measurable. (Aliprantis 1999) This immediately implies that the sigma algebra generated by the $A\left(E,\, p\right)$ is a subset of the Borel sigma-algebra. 

For the converse, it can be shown that basis elements in the weak topology can be described as sets of the form $A\left(E,\, p\right)$, but then the result doesn't follow because sigma-algebras are only closed under countable unions.